# EntityManager injection - NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dao, criteria-api

In my Spring+JPA/Hibernate+Wicket app, I have a QueryBuilder bean that I want to use in one of my DAOs which generates a typed query with the help of Criteria API:

```
@Service(value="inboxQueryBuilder")
public class InboxQueryBuilder {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    CriteriaBuilder cb;

    public InboxQueryBuilder() {
        cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    }

    public TypedQuery<App> getQueryForApps(AppSearchObject aso) {
           ...
    }

    ...
}
```

However, when I run the app, I get a null pointer exception for line:

```
cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
```

i.e. the EntityManager doesn't get injected. Do you know why?

Also, is this use correct and thread-safe or should I instantiate my InboxQueryBuilder for each query? In that case, should I also inject the EntityManager or should I just pass it as a constructor parameter (the InboxQueryBuilder would get instantiated for each query in the DAO which has an injected instance of EntityManager)?

Comment: How do you create InboxQueryBuilder?

Comment: in the example given, it's a spring bean. but i don't know if making it a singleton is good.

Comment: Don't use singletons in a spring project. Use spring singleton beans instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't access the EntityManager within the constructor. Take a look at the @PostConstruct-Annotation

```
@Service(value="inboxQueryBuilder")
public class InboxQueryBuilder {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

CriteriaBuilder cb;

public InboxQueryBuilder() {
    // em= null
}

@PostConstruct
public void toSomething(){
    // em set by Container  
    cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
}


public TypedQuery<App> getQueryForApps(AppSearchObject aso) {
       ...
}

...
}
```

**EDIT:**
After reading your post again, I start to became unsure, if I'm right. I know the Java EE-Dependency-Injection within a JBoss works as I described, but I'm not sure about spring-IOC.

Comment: This is where spring is your friend! It is doing the autowire of the entity manager for you - without spring this would not work - the auto injection of the Entity Manager only works (via the Application Server) if you're running inside an EJB.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this bean somewhere in your application context?

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: yes i do. entitymanager gets injected into the DAO that calls getQueryForApps method without a problem.

Comment: then the comment from seanizer is the answer. You should make it spring singleton

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses the Java Beans mechanism, so I am pretty sure this is insufficient:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

Here's the standard way:

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(final EntityManager entityManager){
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

Comment: OK, do you have autowiring turned on?