# Auto-instantiate session-scoped bean from view-scoped bean

Tags: jsf-2, weblogic-10.x

Every time I try to inject a session-scoped bean into my view-scoped beans, I get a NullPointerException when calling said bean. This problem is directly related to [auto -instantiate a session bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043259/auto-instantiate-a-session-bean)

Here is what I tried so far:

faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>sessionBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.SessionBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>viewBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.ViewBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>sessionBean</property-name>
        <property-class>com.example.SessionBean</property-class>
        <value>#{sessionMBean}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

SessionBean.java:

```
package com.example;

public class SessionBean {

    public SessionBean() {
        System.out.println("Session is instantiated.");
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from session");
    }
}
```

ViewBean.java:

```
package com.example;

public class ViewBean {

    private SessionBean sessionBean;

    private String text = "Look at me!";

    public ViewBean() {
        System.out.println("View bean is instantiated.");

        sessionBean.sayHello();
    }

    public SessionBean getSessionBean() {
        return sessionBean;
    }

    public void setSessionBean(SessionBean sessionBean) {
        this.sessionBean = sessionBean;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

and the relevant content of index.xhtml:

```
<f:view>
    <h:outputText value="#{viewBean.text}"/>
</f:view>
```

And this is what I get:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.example.ViewBean.
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.ViewBean.(ViewBean.java:12)
```

This runs (or rather doesn't run) on weblogic-10.3.6 with the shipped jsf-2-0.war deployed as a library.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm hoping this is not a container bug...

Comment: Try to think in plain Java terms: how is it ever possible to do `viewBean.setSessionBean(sessionBean)` before `viewBean = new ViewBean()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the `@SessionScoped` bean in the `@ViewScoped` constructor. The `@SessionScoped` bean will be set AFTER the constructor of the `@ViewScoped` bean has been called.
Use the `@PostConstruct` annotation in some kind of *init* method to access the `@SessionScoped` bean.

```
public ViewBean() {
  System.out.println("Constructor viewbean");
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  sessionBean.sayHello();
}
```

Further Links:
[Why use @PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct)
[Spring Injection - access to the injected object within a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132437/entitymanager-injection-nullpointerexception)

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense of course. You can't inject into something that has not been created yet.