# Keeping @ViewScoped property states in composite component backings

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

This question is related with my previous one about [initializing composite components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525669/initialize-a-composite-component-based-on-the-provided-attributes). Providing I've got a homegrown composite component and a `@ViewScoped` managed bean, I want certain properties of the managed bean to be reflected in the component. The transition of the property value to the component is done by a **composite attribute**.

That's the code I've got right now, consisting in a `@ManagedBean` which defines a random row number to be rendered at the component. The component generates a `h:dataTable` with a `h:commandButton` in each row, pressing that button just calls a method in the component backing code and **performs a postback to the same view**.

**Managed bean:**

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private Integer rowNum;

    public Integer getRowNum() {
        return rowNum;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the rowNum property with a value between 1 and 9
     */
    public void init() {
        if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
            rowNum = new Random().nextInt(10) + 1;
            System.out.println("Bean initialized");
        }
    }

    public void setRowNum(Integer rowNum) {
        this.rowNum = rowNum;
    }

}
```

**index.xhtml:**

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/comp">
<h:head />
<body>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
    <h:form>
        <comp:myTable itemNumber="#{bean.rowNum}" />
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**MyTable.java:**

```java
@FacesComponent("components.myTable")
public class MyTable extends UINamingContainer {

    private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void action() {
        System.out.println("Called");
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the 'values' List based in 'itemNumber' attribute
     */
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Component initialized");
        Integer num = (Integer) getAttributes().get("itemNumber");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            values.add("item" + i);
        }
    }

}
```

**myTable.xhtml:**

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:body>
    <composite:interface componentType="components.myTable">
        <composite:attribute name="itemNumber" 
            type="java.lang.Integer" required="true" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{cc.init}" />
        <h:dataTable value="#{cc.values}" var="value">
            <h:column headerText="column">
                #{value}
                <h:commandButton value="Action" action="#{cc.action}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Given that [components themselves are stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15553368/1199132), the row number to get rendered must be determined by the `Bean` instance in order not to loose its value when a postback happens.

Either the `@ManagedBean` and the component are initialized by an `init()` method which gets called when `preRenderView` event happens. The `@ManagedBean` checks it's not actually a postback request, considering it has to maintain the view state. The component however, being stateless, doesn't perform that checking because it loses its value in each request and have to be initialized in all of them.

The issue is clicking any of the `h:commandButton` makes an empty `List` to be rendered. It seems like it's being read before the `init()` method gets called. That doesn't happen however when a *GET* request is performed.

A way to avoid that issue is doing a lazy initialization at `getValues()` method, invoking `init()` method there instead of doing it from the view with a `preRenderView` event, despite I consider it not being the most elegant way to go with.

Using `postAddToView` instead of `preRenderView` event to initialize the component neither work, as it is invoked before the `@ManagedBean` gets initialized.

---

*Tested in Mojarra 2.1.27 - 2.2.5 + Tomcat 7*